# Why string values are not getting displayed in angular template under h3 tag?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I am getting Json data from Django rest framework as below:

[image: Json Data]

In Angular, calling the api method as below in service.ts:

```
  getOrdersCount() {
    return this.http.get<Order[]>(this.baseUrl + 'orders_count', {
        headers: this.httpHeaders,
    });
}
```

Order model class is as below:

```
export class Order {
totalorders!: string;
ordersnotready!: string;
orderscompleted!: string;

constructor(totalOrders: string, ordersNotReady: string, ordersCompleted: string) {
    this.totalorders = totalOrders;
    this.ordersnotready = ordersNotReady;
    this.orderscompleted = ordersCompleted;
}
}
```

In component, calling the service class method and fetching the count as below:

```
  export class DashboardCardsComponent implements OnInit {
  totalOrders!: string;
  ordersCompleted!: string;
  ordersNotReady!: string;

constructor(public orderService: OrderService) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.orderService.getOrdersCount().subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
        result.forEach(x => {
            this.totalOrders = x.totalorders.toString();
            this.ordersCompleted = x.orderscompleted.toString();
            this.ordersNotReady = x.ordersnotready.toString();
            console.log(this.totalOrders);
            console.log(this.ordersCompleted);
            console.log(this.ordersNotReady);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Console log for counts is as below:

[image]

Template for displaying the data is:

```
 <div class="row">

 <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-8">
 <div class="card text-white mb-4 bg-primary" >
    
    <div class="card-header">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Total Orders</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title text-center" >{{ totalOrders }}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-8">
    <div class="card text-white mb-4 bg-success">
    
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">Orders Completed</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title text-center">{{ordersCompleted}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-8">
    <div class="card text-white mb-4 bg-danger">
    
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">Not Ready</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title text-center">{{ordersNotReady}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now, the issue is its not rendering the values in template under h3 tags. Its displaying blank values. Why its not displaying the values? Please suggest.

Thanks

**Update:**
Changed the service class as below:

```
getOrdersCount(): Observable<Order> {
    return (
        this.http
            .get<Order>(this.baseUrl + 'orders_count', {
                headers: this.httpHeaders,
            })
            // .pipe(tap(_ => console.log('fetched heroes')));
            .pipe(map((result: Order) => result))
    );
}
```

Changed the component as below:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.orderService.getOrdersCount().subscribe(data => (this.order = 
      data));
}
```

In template, made changes as below:

```
   <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-8">
   <div class="card text-white mb-4 bg-primary" >
    
    <div class="card-header">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Total Orders</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title text-center">{{order.totalorders}}</h3>
    </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

But after this getting the error in console as below:

[image]

Comment: As per my understanding, I have answered below. But it would be great if you share your code using some editor for better understanding.

Comment: @MinalShah I tried your suggestion but still its not showing the data in template. Used forEach to loop through the response from service. Please check the Json data in question.

Comment: You please share your code using some editor.

Comment: Please find the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zhgmkq

Answer (score 0):

Initially it would be not initialized.
All the variables are initialized after the api returns the result.
For resolving this,
just add *ngIf condition in h3 tag.

For example:

```
 <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title text-center" *ngIf="ordersNotReady">{{ordersNotReady}}</h3>
        </div>
```

alongwith that, why have you used **result.forEach()**, What is returned from the api.

Edited::
Hey when I send some random data from service, by not calling the service. It is working fine.
I have updated the service by this:

```
export class OrderService {
    
    baseUrl = 'http://localhost:7000/';
    temp:BehaviorSubject<any>= new BehaviorSubject([{totalorders:23,ordersnotready:34,orderscompleted:45}])
    httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-type': 'application/json' });

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   getOrdersCount() {
    return this.temp
    /* return this.http.get<Order[]>(this.baseUrl + 'orders_count', {
        headers: this.httpHeaders,
    }); */
}

 
}
```

Hey, When I look deep into this. The change is not detected in the html, so when the values fetched by api reach to the subscription, it is not detected in html.

One option is that you can use **ChangeDetectorRef** and call **.detectChanges()** in the subscription.

Or else just add one condition in the main div and bind that with some boolean.
Use the below code of lines:

```
export class DashboardCardsComponent implements OnInit {
  totalOrders!: string;
  ordersCompleted!: string;
  ordersNotReady!: string;
   showTemplate:boolean= true;

constructor(public orderService: OrderService) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.orderService.getOrdersCount().subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.showTemplate=false;
        result.forEach(x => {
            this.totalOrders = x.totalorders.toString();
            this.ordersCompleted = x.orderscompleted.toString();
            this.ordersNotReady = x.ordersnotready.toString();
            console.log(this.totalOrders);
            console.log(this.ordersCompleted);
            console.log(this.ordersNotReady);
        });
       this.showTemplate=true;
    });
  }
}
```

And in html replace the first line:

```
 <div class="row" *ngIf="showTemplate">
```

And one solution would definetly work.

Hey just add question mark in html as shown below.

```
 <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title text-center">{{order?.totalorders}}</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes. its working. So you mean there is some issue in data sent by the server?

Comment: Yes, you just verify that once. Maybe the response you get is not of json type. So you need to convert that in json before using it.

Comment: I am getting the data like this:[{"totalorders": 1259, "ordersnotready": 994, "orderscompleted": 186}]  Is this is a valid json data?

Comment: I have added some additional information, please check that once.

Comment: I tried your second suggestion to add boolean variable but still it did not work. Will look into other option.

Comment: You can add timeout for the line.....  this.showTemplate= true of about 500 ms.

Comment: Added setTimeout(() => (this.showTemplate = true), 500); but still data not showing on template. All the variables are showing as undefined outside the subscribe method.

Comment: Just to update. I changed the server api call to return the data as single object not the array and mapped the api response to the model class by subscribing it in the component. Now I am able to see the counts in the html but getting an error in console that "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalorders' of undefined". totalorders is the property mentioned in the Order class.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the answer, please add that, this would resolve the issue.

Comment: Now console errors are gone but  its also stopped showing the values.

Comment: Okay than you just initialize the order variable in .ts with order= new Order(' ',' ',' ')

Comment: Initialize the order variable but same issue.

Comment: Its working now. The issue was due to the changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush in @Component decorator. After deleting this, its started displaying the values in template's html.